# Can anyone recommend publications of Seneca's work?

Tags: stoicism

Having read [Penguin Great Ideas : On the Shortness of Life](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/014101881X), I am keen to read further works of Seneca. Can anyone recommend any publications?

I have stumbled upon [Anger, Mercy, Revenge (Complete Works of Lucius Annaeus Seneca)](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0226748413) which looks promising.

I am also interested in published commentaries on the work of Seneca.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't read any specific works on [Seneca](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seneca_the_Younger) but the **Complete Works** series looks like it might cover a good amount of ground. Just note that it looks like it's split into 3 books: [Anger, Mercy, Revenge](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0226748413), [On Benefits](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0226748405), and [Natural Questions](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0226748383), rather than just one big book about all of Seneca's work (which you might think would make sense since not very many surviving works which are attributed to him).

[Letters from a Stoic](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0140442103) seems to have gotten mostly favorable reviews, as well as [Stoic Philosophy of Seneca: Essays and Letters](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0393004597) so you might consider checking those out as well if you are looking for alternatives.

Answer (score 2):

The  [Loeb Classical Library](http://www.hup.harvard.edu/collection.php?cpk=1031) has among others the complete works of Seneca one Page the original the facing page an English translation.

Answer (score 0):

Letters to a Stoic is a very interesting read. I am 12 letters in and I believe there is over a hundred letters in all. Each one deals with specific themes and are written to his friend Lucilius.